# Rendering a value as text instead of field inside a Django Form

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

Is there a simple way to make Django render `{{myform.name}}` as

```
John Smith
```

instead of

```
<input id="id_name" name="name" value="John Smith" />
```

inside `<form>` tags? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<form>
    {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.label }}: {{ field.value }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Take a look here [Form fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial) and [Working with forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Comment: Thanks - I had seen .label but not .initial. Curiously, .initial isn't even mentioned in the "Working with forms" document.

Comment: .initial only works the first time the form is presented, right?  For example, if there are errors and you re-present the form, there will be no initial in my experience.

Comment: In Django terminology, this only works with unbound forms.  What if you want it to work with both unbound and bound forms?

Answer (score 20):

Old topic, but I think some people still comes here.

You can do something like this too:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class PlainTextWidget(forms.Widget):
    def render(self, _name, value, _attrs):
        return mark_safe(value) if value is not None else '-'
```

And in your form

```
class SomeForm(Form):
   somename = forms.CharField(widget=PlainTextWidget)
```

Under Django 2.1+ you'll need the following:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class PlainTextWidget(forms.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        return mark_safe(value) if value is not None else '-'
```

Comment: `def render(self, name, value, attrs):` in django 1.10 (?not sure if its in others or why my version requires no underscores?) so no [_name and _attrs]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a new widget: I did this so that I could have a widget that created a text display of a date, and a hidden form with the same date in it, so it could be visible to the user, but they cannot change it.

Here is an initial (still testing/to be cleaned up) version:

```
class DayLabelWidget(forms.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs):
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        if hasattr(self, 'initial'):
            value = self.initial
        if type(value) == type(u''):
            value = datetime.date(*map(int, value.split('-')))
        return mark_safe(
            "%s" % value.strftime("%A (%d %b %Y)")
        ) + mark_safe(
            "<input type='hidden' name='%s' value='%s' />" % (
                name, value
            )
        )

    def _has_changed(self, initial, data):
        return False
```

You then use this in the field as `(widget=DayLabelWidget,)`.

Comment: This approach was very useful for me, because as well as displaying a 'plain' version of the value, it also creates a copy that is passed on when the form is POSTed. I adapted it to make a slightly more general version (see my answer further down)

Comment: Keep in mind that this value could quite easily be changed by a nefarious user. You'd probably want to make the form field return it's initial in clean.

Comment: I’d second that. Techniques like this are very helpful for keeping state in the presentation layer, but ANY item of data sent back from a user form or session must be thoroughly validated if it’s going to be used at the application layer.

Answer (score 6):

Also, don't forget you can also do `{{myform.instance.name}}`

Comment: what is this? where is it documented?

Comment: form.instance returns the object that the bound form is representing. It's in the docs here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method I should also mention that this only works with modelforms

Comment: ah, google app engine does not support ModelForm, so we're using Form.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want: 
http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10427

I patched my django and voila...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a take on the approach suggested by @Matthew_Schinkel above, using Django 2.2 and python 3.

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class PlainTextWidgetWithHiddenCopy(forms.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        if hasattr(self, 'initial'):
            value = self.initial

        return mark_safe(
            (str(value) if value is not None else '-') +
            f"<input type='hidden' name='{name}' value='{value}'>"
        )
```

This is a custom widget that renders the contents of a field as plaintext followed by an html tag that creates a hidden field with the same name and value as the original field.

This means that as well as the value being displayed to the user, it is held by the browser and sent onwards to the view that processes the submitted form.

This is particularly handy if the form POSTs to itself, as the plaintext data would otherwise disappear because the field's `initial` value hadn’t been set.

For example if your form contains:

```
my_field = forms.IntegerField(
    widget=PlainTextWidgetWithHiddenCopy,
    initial=12345)
```

then this field will render as the following html:

```
12345<input type='hidden' name='my_field' value='12345'>
```

When the form is submitted the POST data received by the corresponding view will include:

```
{'my_field': '12345'}
```

This means that if the view now re-renders the form then the value of `my_field` is again set to `12345` just as if the request had been a `GET`.

As Matthew correctly points out in his subsequent comment, this approach provides no significant protection against a user changing the data that’s sent back in the hidden field. “All user input is evil”.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use {{ field.data }} ?

Comment: Because It should be done in views not in template (in template is loop)